# Quartz.net as service can't configure the quartz_job.xml

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

When using

```
            var properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.plugin.triggHistory.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin";

            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin";
            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames"] = "quartz_jobs.xml";
            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval"] = "120";

            // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
            _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

The windows service / quartz cannot resolve the path of quartz_jobs.xml.
If i run this as console it works fine.

```
  public static void StartJobs()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            var properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.plugin.triggHistory.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin";

            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin";
            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames"] = "quartz_jobs.xml";
            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval"] = "120";

            // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
            _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

            // start the schedule 
            _scheduler.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you put the xml file? Is it included in the project? Try "~/quartz_jobs.xml" instead.

Comment: in the root directory, will try.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still not working, include the file as an embedded resource in the project, set the action to Copy always, to be sure. Then provide the full file path to the quartz property:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "quartz_jobs.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is from 2015, but i can't find any information regarding using quartz.net in a windows service. In my case, I am using .Net Core 2.1 Generic Host as a windows service with the quartz_jobs.xml which is referenced in my appsettings.json file. When the windows service starts up an looks for the quartz_job.xml it tries to find it in c:\windows\system32. But my quartz_job.xml is located where my executable is located. I tracked down Method ResolveFile in Quaztz\Util\FileUtil.cs of their repo where is says to put a "~" to for relative file. So I changed my appsettings.json to

```
 "plugin": {
      "jobInitializer": {
        "type": "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz.Plugins",
        "fileNames": "~\\quartz_jobs.xml"
      }
```

and now the windows service is able to read the quartz_jobs.xml. I would expect the if you change

```
 properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames"] = "quartz_jobs.xml";
```

to

```
properties["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames"] = "~\\quartz_jobs.xml";
```

it should also work.